# odbc memory issue while fetching data records for huge data

Tags: php, pagination, odbc, out-of-memory

I am using odbc to connect to DB in PHP. The data records is having millions of records due to which I am getting `PHP Fatal Error: Memory size issue`

Code:

```
while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($prepStmt)) {
                $result[] = $row;
            }
```

Here, `odbc_fetch_array` is fetching millions of records once and storing them in memory at once due to which I am getting Memory size issue.

Is there any way in odbc so that I can fetch the rows in the loop(like 5-10k rows at once and store it in file and then again next 5-10k rows and so on) to reduce the memory consumption?

Note:- One way is to increase the PHP memory limit but I am looking for pagination kind off solution in odbc(as explained above).

Comment: The ODBC extension has [lots of functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php) that retrieve rows one by one, you're specifically using the one that retrieves the complete result-set at once. Do you need chunks of several thousand rows for any special reason?

Comment: What @ÁlvaroGonzález said. F.e. `odbc_fetch_row` or `odbc_fetch_array`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález rows one by one is fine for me(or you can say what I want). I just wanted to use one which returns data as an associative array, that's it. And since odbc_fetch_array() is one that returns an associative array, I used it earlier. Can you suggest any other function in odbc that returns the data in array form but one by one?